# How to apply linear regression to one sensor so that it will match readings from better sensor?

Tags: regression, linear-model, autocorrelation, autoregressive

I have one sensor which has the best accuracy and the other sensor which I want to calibrate using some linear regression (or something else?) - by modifying the software.
How to calculate that linear regression?

For example, the graph looks like this:
[image]

The red one is the one I want to calibrate and the blue one has the best accuracy.

Comment: Have a look at our [help/on-topic] - questions such as "To be more specific: How to calculate that programmatically in Java" are unlikely to be within the scope of the site. I think this question could be on-topic here but would need to be edited and rescoped.

Comment: I edited my question. I just want to know a general answer to that question or just some hints on what should I look for, that would be very helpful. The Java thing was here just in case if somebody had such a solution at hand.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your data, I don't think that you can reliably do what you want. A linear calibration might make some sense if there were fairly consistent offset and gain differences between the sensors. But that's not the case here.

The two sensors agree almost exactly in the third major peak from the left, of the six major peaks displayed. In the second peak from the right, however, with very similar values reported by the accurate sensor, the other sensor reports much lower values. There's no way that the same calibration curve, linear or not, would work consistently over all these data.

It looks more like your less-accurate sensor works well sometimes and has problems at other times. Trying to "calibrate" it to agree better with the accurate sensor would thus be misleading unless you also could model its pattern of developing problems.

Comment: What if I had such a data that fairly consistent offset would be visible?

Comment: Linear regression might work in principle. If you have other such data, consider reformulating your question in a way that emphasizes underlying statistical principles; it still sounds too much like "how can I do linear regression?" rather than "is linear regression an appropriate solution to this problem?" I recommend first plotting the values of the 2 sensors against each other to see the patterns or lack thereof.